# Test to compare cumulative distributions

Tags: distributions, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I would like to compare multiple cumulative distributions, and cluster them accordingly to their 'shape'.
My distributions look like the one in the figure
[image]

on the x axis there are the number of items I measured (sorted from the most to the lowest abundant) and on the y axis the cumulative abundance.
Visually I can see that they look different, but I would like to test that and obtain some sort of value that indicates how much they differ from each other.

I initially thought to perform a two-samples KS test, and use the D statistic to cluster the distributions, hoping to see which sample(s) differ from the others. However, I am not sure this test is the most appropriate.
What I do not know is if the KS test is sensitive to the local density of the data. What I mean is that, looking at the example, it is evident that for sample 1 I would need to sum up ~20 items to arrive at 25% of the total mass, while for sample 2 I need only ~5 items. Similarly, to go up 50% I need ~170 items in sample 1 and ~80 in sample 2.

Comment: Lacking here is a clear motivation for the cluster analysis. Last sentence seems to focus on positive distributions and density near 0. K-S test statistic for 'distance' btw 2 dist'ns is max vertical distance btw the two empirical CDFs. That seems not to be what you're looking for. What attributes of a dist'n _are_ important to you? Symmetry, kurtosis, number of modes, location, scale, ... ?

Comment: There are two things that I would like the test to consider: 1- the rate of the distribution, i.e. how fast the distribution increases (how many items are needed to arrive to a certain % of the total mass); 2- as you said, the distribution near 0, because there are cases where the shape of 2 distributions is quite similar, but in one Q1-Q2 are 'occupied' but much much less items than the other distribution, which are then 'level out' in Q3